# Unable to run PHPUnit Test with relative include path

Tags: php, phpunit

I am doing an assignment and I was asked not to modify the Test File (**CheckPayTest.php**). I try to run test but phpunit cannot find the file and the file is correctly placed in the directory. Is it possible to make phpunit see this file when running the test

**CheckPayTest.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace cms\tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class CheckPayTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_File_Read()
    {
        $readFile = include './../Creative.php';

        self::assertTrue($readFile);
    }
}
```

File to include **Creative.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace cms;

return true;
```

**phpunit.xml Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

**Error**

```
1) cms\tests\CheckPayTest::test_File_Read
include(./../Creative.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Could this problem be solved without modifying **CheckPayTest.php**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make it run without modifying `CheckPayTest.php`.

Unfortunately someone who wrote this test was not aware of how php executable resolves relative directory paths - so the problem jumped out.

The solution is to change the directory from where php script starts to execute - php resolves relative paths from within any file during execution in reference to entry point of script start. The solution is to cd (change directory) to where this path `'./../Creative.php'` becomes valid and run phpunit script from there.

Anyway, this solution is really poor - the correct way to fix it is to change first dot from the path to php magic constant `__DIR__` which always provide absolute path to directory in which code was executed. I think you should change this file anyway - otherwise it will remain poorly written.

Try to change `'./../Creative.php'` into `__DIR__ . '/../Creative.php'`

Comment: Okay I have no choice than to modify the file. Your answer was helpful. The magic constant solved the problem. I just hope my solution would be accepted after modifying the file. The file has various relative paths to include different files so it's difficult to cd into one folder and run phpunit. Some file may include others will fail

Comment: Thats why always when working with paths in PHP use these magic constants - the good side is that this change will not break the existing code.